# Table creation error using Hibernate and H2

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm trying to run a test that uses H2 in-memory database and hibernate.
But I get the following error during context start-up:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in
> SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ANIMAL (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, CREATIONDATE
> DATETIME, CREATOR VARCHAR(255), LASTMODIFICATION DATETIME,
> LASTMODIFIEDBY VARCHAR(255), VERSION BIGINT, ALLERGIES VARCHAR(255),
> ANAMNESIS VARCHAR(255), BREED VARCHAR(255), COMMENT VARCHAR(255),
> DATEOFBIRTH DATETIME, DECEASED BIT NOT NULL, DIET VARCHAR(255),
> HUSBANDRY VARCHAR(255), IDCODE VARCHAR(255), NAME VARCHAR(255), SEX
> INTEGER, WEIGHT FLOAT, FK_OWNER BIGINT, TAXONOMY_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY
> KEY (ID)) ENGINE=[*]MYISAM"; expected "identifier";

What am I doing wrong?
Here is application.properties file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

The same error is repeating for all databases that hibernate tries to create:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement
> "CREATE TABLE HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE (NEXT_VAL BIGINT) ENGINE=[*]MYISAM";
> expected "identifier"

Comment: In the creation script do you have each instruction in a single line?

Comment: yes, the script is actually generated by Hibernate

Comment: Add Animal entity class.

Answer (score 1):

So at the end issue was in configuration file where I had wrong lines:

```
Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return properties;
}
```

changed it with:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
```

And all started working fine

Comment: Are you using `Spring`?

Comment: Thanks! The dialect was my problem, too